# Learning Vim after vimtutor

Tags: help-system

What should the next steps to learning Vim be, after completing `vimtutor`? I've watched videos on YouTube, read tutorials online and questions/answers on SE, and am busy reading [Practical](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) Vim.

Are there any other good resources available? Actually practicing and using Vim -- not just watching/reading about it -- is surely a good way to learn. Any suggestions on the best way to use the built-in help system to learn Vim?

PS: Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567883/does-an-updated-vimtutor-exist) question on SO has been closed for being off-topic, several of the answers there look useful.

PPS: I used vim many years ago, moved to Emacs for Org-Mode, and am now returning to vim :)

Comment: Your question might be also closed because SE sites are for precises questions and yours might be too broad. Other than that Pratical Vim is an **amazing** book and reading it is a really good idea. After that I think the best way to learn is to use vim daily and each time you find something which feels unatural (or against vim philosophy) you note it down and try to find a better way to do it.

Comment: If you're using Vim for keybindings, consider [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Sharpen the saw

The best general advice is a simple one, "[Sharpen the saw](http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html)" from Bram's Seven habits essay. I also suggest [Vimcasts blog](http://vimcasts.org/) post: [On sharpening the saw](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2012/08/on-sharpening-the-saw/).

Basically "sharpening the saw" can be summarized as:

> Don't learn everything all at once, but learn a few things at a time.
>   When you find an inefficiency look for ways to improve it. Repeat

#### Vimrc

I also recommend you use [nearly blank vimrc](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc). You should roughly understand each line in your `vimrc`. Use `:help` and google learn more.

#### Plugins

General plugin advice:

- Slowly add a plugin or two when the need arises.
- Do not install a plugin without looking for a native solution first
- Must have good documentation
- Avoid plugins with many mappings
- If it doesn't feel Vim-like then avoid it
- Avoid if there are mappings that don't work with the `.` command (may have to use [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat))

#### More good places to learn more about Vim

- [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) - Great articles and screencasts by Drew Neil, the author of *Practical Vim*.
- [Derek Wyatt's Vim Videos](http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/) - Good collection of Vim topics.
- [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) - Steve Losh teaches how to customize Vim from the basics to the more advanced.

#### TL;DR

Read `:help` and try to make small incremental changes to your workflow.

Comment: Personally I have a huge vimwiki page where I take notes, kind of a cookbook, most of it comes from questions on stackexchange, along with all suggestions above I think it is a great idea do make your own. Mine is here: https://bitbucket.org/sergio/dotfaster/raw/b2903f49e8e8de0803acc987aaff7f337b2fcb70/vim/wiki/dicasvim.md

Answer (score 3):

I heartily recommend this tutorial adaptation, for EX-tra Vim power: http://dahu.github.io/vim_waz_ere/

Answer (score 3):

You can learn a great deal by following the questions and answers on the `vim` or `vim_use` mailing list, http://vim.sourceforge.net/maillist.php#vim. While this StackExchange site is great for simple questions and answers, the mailing list is better for questions that require some discussion.