# How to install NERDTree with Vundle?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I'm starting to use Vim and I chose Vundle instead of Pathogen.

I would like to know if I can install the NERDTree using Vundle.

I'm starting Vim and searching for NERDTree like this:

```
:BundleSearch NERDTree
```

But it is not finding the plugin, only:

```
"Keymap: i - Install plugin; c - Cleanup; s - Se|
arch; R - Reload list                           |~                                               
"Search results for: NERDTree                   |~                                               
Plugin 'nerdtree-ack'                           |~                                               
Plugin 'FindInNERDTree'
```

Comment: As a new user, you shouldn't install any plugin. Get used to vanilla Vim first *then* look for solutions to your problems as you encounter them. *some* of those solutions will be plugins but some others won't. Case in point: Vim already comes with a file explorer so you don't *need* to install another one… and you don't *need* a plugin manager either.

Comment: [Be](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) [careful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23410647/438329) [installing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23121220/438329) [plugins](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3a7a6z/netrw_nerdtree/) [too](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2jmxc9/vimmers_you_dont_need_nerdtree/) [early](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2y8iew/they_say_do_not_use_nerdtree_like_browsers_but/) in your Vim journey. General advice: [Learning Vim after vimtutor](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4119/778)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Below is the empty Vundle config.

```
set nocompatible 
filetype off

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Now if you want to add a new plugin example 
[nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree)

you just add the line

**`Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'`**

now the vimrc will look like this

```
set nocompatible 
filetype off

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
" added nerdtree
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Now, just save the vimrc and restart vim so it can source the new vimrc then issue the **:PluginInstall command:**

```
:PluginInstall
```

more information on using can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vundle-to-manage-vim-plugins-on-a-linux-vps)

Comment: Rather than restarting, consider just running the command `source ~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I also followed above steps and it works now.